# White screen on hosting my React app on vercel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, hosting, vercel

I have a full stack blog application, my backend got easily hosted, but the frontend is creating trouble. When I tried hosting on render.com, it said error: stack full. It got hosted on vercel but the screen appears for a second and gets whitewashed. It works perfectly fine when I host it locally.

Here take a look at some of the files->

**Package.json**

```
{
    "name": "frontend",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "proxy": "https://blog-main-cw2a.onrender.com/",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^32.0.0",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^4.0.0",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
        "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "axios": "^0.25.0",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
        "uuid": "^8.3.2",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    }
}
```

**App.js**

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom'
import PrivateRoute from './components/Routing/PrivateRoute';
import Home from "./components/GeneralScreens/Home"
import LoginScreen from "./components/AuthScreens/LoginScreen"
import RegisterScreen from "./components/AuthScreens/RegisterScreen"
import ForgotPasswordScreen from "./components/AuthScreens/ForgotPasswordScreen"
import ResetPasswordScreen from "./components/AuthScreens/ResetPasswordScreen"
import AddStory from './components/StoryScreens/AddStory';
import DetailStory from './components/StoryScreens/DetailStory';
import Header from './components/GeneralScreens/Header';
import Footer from './components/GeneralScreens/Footer';
import Profile from './components/ProfileScreens/Profile';
import EditProfile from './components/ProfileScreens/EditProfile';
import ChangePassword from './components/ProfileScreens/ChangePassword';
import NotFound from './components/GeneralScreens/NotFound';
import EditStory from './components/StoryScreens/EditStory';
import ReadListPage from './components/ProfileScreens/ReadListPage';

const App = () => {

      return (
            <Router>

                  <div className="App">

                        <Routes>
                              <Route path="/" element={<LayoutsWithHeader />}>

                                    <Route path='*' element={<NotFound />} />

                                    <Route exact path='/' element={<PrivateRoute />}>
                                          <Route exact path='/' element={<Home />} />
                                    </Route>

                                    <Route exact path="/story/:slug" element={<DetailStory />} />

                                    <Route exact path='/addstory' element={<PrivateRoute />}>
                                          <Route exact path='/addstory' element={<AddStory />} />
                                    </Route>

                                    <Route exact path='/profile' element={<PrivateRoute />}>
                                          <Route exact path='/profile' element={<Profile />} />
                                    </Route>

                                    <Route exact path='/edit_profile' element={<PrivateRoute />}>
                                          <Route exact path='/edit_profile' element={<EditProfile />} />
                                    </Route>

                                    <Route exact path='/change_Password' element={<PrivateRoute />}>
                                          <Route exact path='/change_Password' element={<ChangePassword />} />
                                    </Route>

                                    <Route exact path='/story/:slug/like' element={<PrivateRoute />}>
                                          <Route exact path='/story/:slug/like' element={<DetailStory />} />
                                    </Route>

                                    <Route exact path='/story/:slug/edit' element={<PrivateRoute />}>
                                          <Route exact path='/story/:slug/edit' element={<EditStory />} />
                                    </Route>

                                    <Route exact path='/story/:slug/delete' element={<PrivateRoute />}>
                                          <Route exact path='/story/:slug/delete' element={<DetailStory />} />
                                    </Route>
                                    <Route exact path='/story/:slug/addComment' element={<PrivateRoute />}>
                                          <Route exact path='/story/:slug/addComment' element={<DetailStory />} />
                                    </Route>

                                    <Route exact path='/readList' element={<PrivateRoute />}>
                                          <Route exact path='/readList' element={<ReadListPage />} />
                                    </Route>

                              </Route>

                              <Route exact path="/login" element={<LoginScreen />} />
                              <Route exact path="/register" element={<RegisterScreen />} />

                              <Route exact path="/forgotpassword" element={<ForgotPasswordScreen />} />

                              <Route exact path="/resetpassword" element={<ResetPasswordScreen />} />


                        </Routes>

                  </div>

            </Router>

      );

}

const LayoutsWithHeader = () => {
      return (
            <>
                  <Header />
                  <Outlet />
                  <Footer />
            </>
      );
}

export default App;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import AuthContextProvider from './Context/AuthContext'

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AuthContextProvider>
       <App />
    </AuthContextProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**file structure**

[click here to see the file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYpGT.png)